# Basic rings (e.g. non commutative) $A$ such $A^n \simeq A^m$ and $n\neq m$

Tags: ring-theory, modules

EDIT : precision and broadening of my question.

Almost all is in the title : I am looking for various structures $A$ such $A^n$ and $A^m$ (products of $A$) are isomorphic (in the sense that it is compatible with at least one structure of $A$, e.g. group or ring if $A$ is a ring...) and moreover $n\neq m$

For example, I'm looking for groups, rings, modules, vector spaces (when the sets at stake exist), whichever commutative or not. 
Simple and basic examples are welcome, I am not researcher...

Extension possible of the question to $A^{(I)} \simeq A^{(J)}$ (external direct sums for structures for which this makes sense) with $card(I)\neq card(J)$.

This question may be a classic one but I can't find the answer neither in book nor here. Please redirect me if possible...

Thanks

Edit bis : references are welcome (it doesn't mean I dont trust answers, but often, books have very interesting comments before or after examples that can't always be put in the answers here... ;))

Comment: By $A^n$ do you mean the usual product $\underbrace{A \times \cdots \times A}_n$?

Comment: "commutative, non commutative, **modules**..."?! This does not make sense in that list. Please clarfiy the question.

Comment: Yes, please write complete sentences for your question. Stack Exchange has a lot of disk space, so refusing to type complete sentences just makes it harder for answerers to help you.

Comment: The question is answered for rings; it takes a little bit more work to find an example of a ring $A$ for which $A^n \simeq A^m$ as left $A$-modules, for $n \neq m$. You should clarify whether or not that's a part of your question.

Comment: OK, sorry, I thought it was clear enough. I'm going to detail :).

Comment: It's edited. Please tell me if it is precise enough or if I have to work again. :)

Comment: @DustanLevenstein : what do you mean by "the question is answered" ?

Comment: @Carrérond at the time I wrote the comment, Clement Guerin's answer addressed the question of an example of a ring $A$ for which $A^n \simeq A^m$ *as rings*, $n \neq m$. Now rschwieb has written an answer which addresses the module interpretation of your question as well.

Comment: Yes, but Clément gave an answer for a field. Is there such an example with a ring which is not a field ?

Comment: @Carrérond The rings $A$ and $B$ that Clement defined are not fields... The rings $A_n$ for $n \in \mathbb N$ could be any ring, as long as $A_n = A_m$ for all $n, m$, the same example works.

Comment: Oh yes, sorry, I focused on the $\mathbb{Z}_2$...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The two standard examples (given in multiple places on the site, but perhaps not easy to find directly) are these:

If $F$ is a field, and $R=\prod_{i\in \Bbb N}F$ is the *ring* direct product, then $R\cong R^m$ *as rings* for whatever positive integer $m$ you wish.

On the other hand, it is impossible for $R^m\cong R^n$ with $n\neq m$ *as modules* for a nonzero commutative ring $R$. The standard example to find a ring $R$ to allow such an isomorphism is the ring of linear transformations $End(V_k)$ of an infinite dimensional $k$-vector space $V$. It is possible to show that $R\cong R^m$ *as $R$ modules* for any positive integer $m$ in this ring.

Comment: OK, I'm looking at that also. Do you have hints for the demonstration of these examples, or references (books, articles...), please ?

Comment: I found the second example well explained in Roman, _Advanced Linear Algebra_, example 5.1 p. 129. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Well it may be very simple but if you take for $A_n:=\mathbb{Z}_2$ (the field with two elements) then :

$$B:=\Pi_{n\in\mathbb{N}}A_n$$

The laws on this ring  $B$ are direct product laws.

$$A:=\oplus_{n\in\mathbb{N}}A_n$$

The ring $A$ is defined to be the subset of $B$ whose all components except a finite number are null. One can show that it is both stable by addition and multiplication (Actually it is an ideal of $B$) but it does not contain the unit element.

You can easily show that $A^n=A^m$ and $B^n=B^m$ for any $n,m$.

Comment: Never "too" simple, I'm going to study that. Merci ;).

Comment: Perhaps you could clarify what structures (as rings or as modules etc) you want things things to be considered as. Right now it's a little ambiguous what you intend your examples to do.

Comment: It's a little tricky... I keep on thinking about that !